# Regex for random number

Tags: regex

Well I got like tons of lines like this:

```
Line 60166: £5.99
Line 60294: £59.99
Line 60493: £5.53
Line 60619: £5.19
Line 60829: £5.88
Line 60847: £5.18
Line 61508: £5.98
Line 61771: £5.27
Line 61777: £5.99
Line 61789: £5.49
Line 61893: £5.00
Line 61899: £5.49
Line 61940: £500.91
```

I want to search for lets say only £500+
So is there an expression like to search £5[AnyNum][AnyNum]? I know its possible I done it before but I forgot what it was

Comment: U want line numbers for 500+ ??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  you cannot be bothered to think what you did before

Comment: What I did before? Over 2 years ago. I have no clue on how to use Notepad++ and regex stuff. I was given the regex before by asking a guy on skype who I no longer know

Comment: Why close this question? Think of other SO users that will benefit from from this question.

Comment: Should £1000.00 pass the check? Your £5[AnyNum] is different from £[numberGreaterThan500]

Comment: Regex is not exempt to the rule of "you must make an attempt first". It's practically a programming language on it's own, and nobody should be expected to do your job for you.

Comment: Any question can be solved by a careful study of relevant documentation. Lets downvote them all.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a different approach to parsing numbers maybe, but the following regex should do what you want:

```
/£[5-9]\d{2,}|£[1-9]\d{3,}/g
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wO7cZ2/2)

To get the line number, not the amount:

```
/(\d+): £[5-9]\d{2,}|(\d+): £[1-9]\d{3,}/g
```

[DEMO2](https://regex101.com/r/wO7cZ2/3)

Version to match decimals:

```
/£[5-9]\d{2,}\.\d{2}|£[1-9]\d{3,}\.\d{2}/g
```

Comment: What about £1000.00? Will it be picked up?

Comment: Yes it will be. Did you see the demo? @sixtytrees

Comment: You are faster than me.

Comment: It's not matching the decimals.

Comment: It doesn't have to, OP wants the line number @Andrew

Comment: I'm not sure, I think he might have misunderstood AB Udhay's question. From the question I think he wants the values.

Comment: @mmm what about `£01484.94`?

Comment: The data doesn't seem to contain ridiculous numbers @mnv

Comment: @Andrew yes might be... I've adjusted the answer with a version that matches the decimals too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try using [5-9] for thundred's digit and [1-9] for thousands+ digit:

```
/£0*([5-9]\d*|[1-9]\d+)\d{2}/g
```

Comment: With 5000, 6000, etc., it only matches 500, 600, etc. This will also match the number after "Line".

Answer (score 0):

If you need values greater than £500.00, including £12345.67 you need to account for two cases:

Number is between 500.00 and 999.99 and number is any 3+ digits. This regex should work.

```
  /(\d+): £[5-9]\d{2,}|(\d+): £[1-9]\d{3,}/g
```

To match dot and fractional part use:

```
 (£[5-9]\d{2,}|£[1-9]\d{3,})(\.)([0-9])([0-9])
```

This will pick up £1000.000 or £1000.00.00. Next expression checks for natural ending of price (space or [`.`, `,`, `;`, `;`, `'`, `"`] followed by space). This regex might miss some strings. For instance, string like `£1000.00+` will be excluded.

```
 (£[5-9]\d{2,}|£[1-9]\d{3,})(\.)([0-9])([0-9])($| |[,.;':'"][ ])
```

https://regex101.com/r/wO7cZ2/3

Use second string if you are OK with some false positives. Expand third string to deal with false positive at a risk of false negative.

Comment: It's matching the line number and not matching the decimals.

Comment: It is matching now.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the value with all its decimals with the '£' included (I'm supposing decimals are optional):

```
£([5-9]\d{2,}|[1-9]\d{3,})(\.\d{1,})*
```

If you don't want the pound sign:

```
(?<=£)([5-9]\d{2,}|[1-9]\d{3,})(\.\d{1,})*
```